# A problem about incidence graph of Projective plane?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I'm doing some research about a kind of families of graphs including incidence graph of some graphs? I want to know how it affect the graphs and the eigenvalues? besides, Do you know how I can study about incidence graph of Projective plane and its spectrum? What is this graph and its eigenvalues?

Comment: What do you mean by "incidence graph of Projective plane? Of course I know what the "incidence graph" of any (hyper-)graph is, but "Projective plane" has more than one meaning.

Comment: "Projective plane" has more than one meaning?